# How can I make HTML elements be hidden by JavaScript, and show up when I click a button?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a website that tells a story, and loads all pages when it's opened, but I need help in coding correctly the pages of the story to be hidden by Javascript, so when a "next" icon is clicked, it shows the hidden page with a "fade in" effect, after "fading out" the previous page. I have searched and learned how to "fade out" an element when clicked, but I also need to make the next element that "fades in" take the space of the previous one. I am very new to web development, and I would be very glad if someone helped me out with this problem. **Also, I don't use jQuery, just normal Javascript.**

```js
function fade(element) {
    var op = 1;  // initial opacity
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        if (op <= 0){
            clearInterval(timer);
            element.style.display = 'none';
        }
        element.style.opacity = op;
        element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
        op -= op * 0.1;
    }, 50);
}

function unfade(element) {
    var op = 0.1;  // initial opacity
    element.style.display = 'block';
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        if (op >= 1){
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
        element.style.opacity = op;
        element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
        op += op * 0.1;
    }, 10);
}
```

```css
.page1 {
  font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
  font-size: 4.9em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10% 0% 0% 0%;
}

.start {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="page1">
        <p>A Short Story</p>
        
        <p class="start" onclick="fade(this)">Click here to start reading</p>
    </div>

    <div class="page2">
        <img onclick="fade()" src="next.ico">
    </div>

  <div class="page3">
        <img onclick="fade()" src="next.ico">
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

As you can see, when you run the code in the snippet, only the clickable text "fades out", but what I wish to do is to make the whole text in the page "fade out". What is the best way to do this, and how can I make the next div element in the body element "fade in", and take the previous div element's space on the page?

Comment: Could you post a fiddle of this? One thing you should consider is using CSS transitions, which will eliminate the need to manually adjust an elements opacity over an interval of time.

Comment: Your *fade* function require an element be passed as an argument, but you're not passing one. Make all the listeners `fade(this.parentNode)` so as to pass a reference to the parent div. There are other schemes for identifying the element to fade.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm for reducing the opacity reduces geometrically and only reaches zero after a very long time (basically the number runs out of precision):

```
element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
op -= op * 0.1;
```

If you want to continue with that algorithm, then the test for ending the loop and hiding the element should use a (suitably small) value other than zero, e.g.

```
if (op <= 0.01) {
```

The *unfade* seems to be OK, but rather than setting *display* to "block", set it to empty string so the element adopts its inherited or default style (whatever that might be), so:

```
element.style.display = '';
```

Now you need to put together the logic to fade one element out, then fade the next one in. You might make a function that initially hides all the pages, then when clicked, hides the current page and shows the next. For that, the *unfade* function needs a callback that runs after the timeout is cleared.

```js
// Use an IIFE so that variables that are
// convenient as globals are kept private in
// a closure
var showNext = (function () {
  var pages = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.page'));
  var currentPage = null;
  
  return function() {
    // If the first time the function has been called,
    // hide all pages and show the first
    if (currentPage === null) {
      pages.forEach(function(page){
        page.style.display = 'none';
      });
      currentPage = 0
      unfade(pages[currentPage]);
      return;
    }
    
    // Otherwise, hide current page and show next
    var nextPage = (currentPage + 1) % pages.length;
    fade(pages[currentPage], function() {
      unfade(pages[nextPage]);
    });
    // Update current page
    currentPage = nextPage;
  };
}());

function fade(element, callback) {
  var op = 1; // initial opacity
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (op <= 0.1) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      element.style.display = 'none';
      // Call callback if provided
      callback && callback();
    }
    element.style.opacity = op;
    element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
    op -= op * 0.1;
  }, 50);
}

function unfade(element) {
  var op = 0.1; // initial opacity
  element.style.display = '';
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (op >= 1) {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
    element.style.opacity = op;
    element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
    op += op * 0.1;
  }, 10);
}

showNext();
```

```html
<div class="page">
  page 1
  <button onclick="showNext()">Next Page&hellip;</button>
</div>

<div class="page">
  page 2
  <button onclick="showNext()">Next Page&hellip;</button>
</div>

<div class="page">
  page 3
  <button onclick="showNext()">Next Page&hellip;</button>
</div>

<button onclick="showNext()">Next Page&hellip;</button>
```

The button to get the next page can be inside or outside the pages.